# How do I force xslt transformation to load data into cdata sections?

Tags: xslt, saxon

I have a client who requires all text in the xml I supply them with to be in CDATA sections. I understand that text should not need to be in CDATA as it has already been parsed and transformed when it is supplied to the client. However, no matter how sure I am, they still need the CDATA sections. Sigh.

I am processing my data with Saxon 9.3, using the command line transform command.

Comment: Do you need to distinguish between "text" elements and other elements or would transforming `<a>42</a>` to `<b><![CDATA[42]]></b>` be valid?

Comment: @Filburt No, no distinction is necessary - they require all data (irrespective of type) to be within CDATA. So yes, `<b><![CDATA[42]]></b>` would be exactly what they want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well as your question title talks about XSLT and your question is flagged as XSLT, the XSLT way to ensure a result element's content is serialized as a CDATA section is to use the `cdata-section-elements` attribute on the `xsl:output` element (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#serialization) listing all elements you want to output as CDATA sections. Thus if you know the elements you want to output as CDATA sections when writing the stylesheet it is a simple as listing them in that attribute. 
Does that help? Or do you want to postprocess arbitrary XML with XSLT to add CDATA sections?

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
 cdata-section-elements="num"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when this transformation is applied on the following sample XML document:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the result has all text nodes (all of them are children of `num` elements) represented within CDATA sections**:

```
<nums>
   <num><![CDATA[01]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[02]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[03]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[04]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[05]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[06]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[07]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[08]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[09]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[10]]></num>
</nums>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using the identity rule to output every node as is.
2. Using the `cdata-section-elements` attribute of `xsl:output` to specify the space-separated list of elements, whose text-node children must be serialized as CDATA sections.

**Do note**: In your case it would be convenient not to modify your existing transformations at all, but to have a post-processing step on their results that is similar to this example.

Comment: Perfect for my needs, nicely explained but there can be only one winner!

Comment: @TheArtfulBenny: This is shared knowledge -- *all* are winners.