# Wrap some fields in CDATA but not others OF THE SAME NAME

Tags: xslt

Forking from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465560/how-do-i-force-xslt-transformation-to-load-data-into-cdata-sections) I asked, how do I ensure that `example/one/field` and `example/three/field` are enclosed in CDATA whilst `example/two/field` is not?

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
  <one>
    <field>CDATA required here</field>
  </one>
  <two>
    <field>No CDATA thanks</field>
  </two>
  <three>
    <field>More CDATA please</field>
  </three>
</example>
```

**Required output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
  <one>
    <field><![CDATA[CDATA required here]]></field>
  </one>
  <two>
    <field>No CDATA thanks</field>
  </two>
  <three>
    <field><![CDATA[More CDATA please]]></field>
  </three>
</example>
```

I could specify `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="field"/>` but this will affect `example/two/field` as well. I have tried putting in a path like `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="example/one/field example/three/field"/>` but this produces an error (*Error XTSE0280: Invalid element name. Invalid QName {example/one/field}*). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current markup I don't think there is a clean way with XSLT. You would need to use different element names or different namespaces at least to allow you and the XSLT processor's serializer to distinguish which elements to output as CDATA sections and which not.

Or you would need to consider to use disable-output-escaping e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="one/field | three/field">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<![CDATA[]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

[edit]
Here is a complete sample stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="one/field | three/field">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<![CDATA[]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note however that disable-output-escaping is an optional serialization feature that is not supported by all XSLT processors.

Comment: Thank you. This isn't what I expected but it does work! I was expecting to find a simple way of restructuring my `cdata-section-elements` attribute so that a path could be specified rather than just an element. I wonder if this functionality will be added in any future specification...

Comment: Using disable-output-escaping is often considered a hack in the XSLT world but in this case I don't know of a clean solution. As for future versions, http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-30/#XML_CDATA-SECTION-ELEMENTS does not suggest any major changes for the upcoming XSLT version 3.0. But you could try to make suggestions or feature requests on the W3C list perhaps.