# How to include CDATA when writing Saxon's XdmNode to Stream in C#

Tags: c#, xslt, transform, cdata, saxon

I have an XdmNode object generated by a transform that I need to write to a stream that includes some CDATA, but I cannot get the output to include the CDATA escaping.

Is this because I'm not going through the process of serialization, eg, using the Serializer class?  If so, how do I do this?  I can see the Serializer class has a serializeNode() method in Java, but not in C#... only the transform/etc seem to be able to "use" it.  Or is this a problem around the cdata-section-elements statement?

Using the XML and XSLT from here to illustrate:
[How do I force xslt transformation to load data into cdata sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465560/how-do-i-force-xslt-transformation-to-load-data-into-cdata-sections)

This uses .NET 4.5 with Saxon 9.6.0.6 in C#.

C# code:

```
Processor processor = new Processor();
XdmNode node = GetNode(processor);  //gets XdmNode for XML doc below
XsltTransformer transformer = GetTransformer(processor);  //gets transform below

transformer.InitialContextNode = node;
XdmDestination output = new XdmDestination();
transformer.Run(output);
string results = output.XdmNode.OuterXml;

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out))
{
    output.XdmNode.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
  cdata-section-elements="num"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

Expected output:

```
<nums>
   <num><![CDATA[01]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[02]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[03]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[04]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[05]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[06]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[07]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[08]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[09]]></num>
   <num><![CDATA[10]]></num>
</nums>
```

Actual output (both on the console and in the string):

```
<nums>
    <num>01</num>
    <num>02</num>
    <num>03</num>
    <num>04</num>
    <num>05</num>
    <num>06</num>
    <num>07</num>
    <num>08</num>
    <num>09</num>
    <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

Comment: Do you need the `XdmDestination` for other reasons? Or are you use looking for a way to write a file with CDATA sections and other options defined with `xsl:output`? In that case use http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Serializer.html instead of XdmDestination.

Comment: @Martin - yes, we need the transform to create an XdmNode for other reasons (as always, the real problem behind the code above is a lot more complex).  If it helps: we have one part of our codebase that does a variety of transformations and works with XdmNodes, and another part that will sometimes take some of these and write the XdmNodes out to streams (over HTTP).  It's this latter area we have problems with - the receiving end (not always in our control) doesn't see the CDATA markup (just the XML) where it should be (recreated above so we think it's the streaming out not the reading in).

Comment: Well the XSLT/XPath/XQuery data model that XdmNode represents does not know any CDATA section so when your transformation creates XdmNodes they do not contain any CDATA sections as that is syntactic sugar on the serialization level that is not represented in the tree model of nodes.

Comment: Ah.  That's where I'm going wrong - thanks. There is a 2nd serializer class in net.sf.saxon.s9api (the one I mentioned above is in the Saxon.Api namespace) that would appear to support setting output properties (eg, cdata-section-elements), writing to a stream, and has the serializeNode(XdmNode node) method - is this the right path to go down?  And if so, does anyone have any hints about using .NET streams with the (presumably) IKVM'd java.io.Stream class that this serializer accepts? (and should this be a separate SO question?)

Comment: Sorry, I think you have to wait until Michael Kay or someone else of Saxonica shows up to answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you want to do is to send an XdmNode to a Serializer to have it serialized with the properties that are set on the Serializer. The easiest way to do this is probably to run a dummy query:

```
QueryCompiler qc = Processor.NewQueryCompiler();
QueryEvaluator qe = qc.Compile(".").Load();
qe.ContextItem = xdmNode;
qe.Run(serializer);
```

The XQuery expression "." simply returns the context item.

Incidentally, the API documentation for Serializer doesn't say what form the CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS property should take, but I think it is probably a whitespace separated sequence of QNames in Clark notation, that is `Q{uri}local`. Or just the local name if there are no namespaces.

(This is similar to the approach often used in the Java JAXP interface of running an "identity transformation". But an identity query is much simpler.)

Comment: Thanks - we were considering the identity transform also; good to know there is a simpler alternative.